# aliasing custom elements in aurelia templates

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, aurelia

My question is about aliasing custom elements and using them in aurelia's html-templates.
As setup i'm using the newest webpack typescript skeleton https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation
and these are my configs:

**webpack.config.a.js**

```
...
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  modules: [srcDir, 'node_modules'],
  alias: {
    "component-alias": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/component-a")
  }
},
...
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="component-alias/component"></require>
  <require from="./nav-bar.html"></require>

  <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>

  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
  <component></component>
</template>
```

**file structure:**

```
src
|----component-a
|    |----component.html
|    |----component.ts
|
|----component-b
|    |----component.html
|    |----component.ts
|
|----app.html
|----app.ts
|
|...
|
webpack.config.a.js
webpack.config.b.js
```

Depending on different configs (`webpack.config.a.js, webpack.config.b.js`), webpack should decide at buildtime if component-a or component-b is part of the bundle.
With the configs webpack compiles but at runtime an exception is thrown:

```
Error: Unable to find module with ID: component-alias/component.html
```

Is it possible to instantiate these components within the html-templates?
Or maybe there are other approaches how to decide at build time which component to use?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.
Using aurelia's built-in `compose` element does the trick.

**app.html**

```
<template>    
  <require from="./nav-bar.html"></require>

  <nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>

  <div class="page-host">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
  <compose view-model.bind="componentPath"
           view.bind="componentTemplatePath"></compose>
</template>
```

**app.ts**

```
import { PLATFORM } from "aurelia-pal";
...
public bind() {
  this.componentPath = PLATFORM.moduleName("component-alias/component");
  this.componentTemplatePath = PLATFORM.moduleName("component-alias/component.html");
}
```

I think it's not the best solution, but it's a working one. If you have any alternative approaches, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I have a suspicion that just `PLATFORM.moduleName("component-alias/component.html")` somewhere in the code would be enough and `compose` is not needed